# eks with istio ALB not being created

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio

I'm trying to create an EKS cluster with terraform and configure it thorugh kubectl and istio basic following this guides:

[alb-ingress-controller](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/aws-elastic-kubernetes-service-running-alb-ingress-controller/)

[istio-alb](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/istio-external-aws-application-loadbalancer-and-istio-ingress-gateway/)

However when trying to deploy the alb, it does not create any alb on aws.

Ruunning `kubectl get ingress -n istio-system`, I get:

```
NAME   CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
alb    <none>   *                 80      4s
```

I'm unable to debug it as I can't find any log telling me why the alb is not deployed. Does anynone came across the same issue? Or does anyone have any clues on how to pin-point the issue?

Follow config files used:

ingress-alb.yaml

```
    ---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: alb
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    # create AWS Application LoadBalancer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "***"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "****"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
              servicePort: 80
```

`kubectl -n istio-system get svc istio-ingressgateway`

```
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   NodePort   **************   <none>        15021:30012/TCP,80:31684/TCP,443:30689/TCP   132m
```

eks_cluster.tf

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
  name = module.eks_cluster.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "eks" {
  name = module.eks_cluster.cluster_id
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks.token
}
module "eks_cluster" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"

  cluster_version = "1.18"
  cluster_name    = var.eks.cluster_name
  vpc_id          = *****
  subnets         = *****
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  enable_irsa     = true
  

  worker_groups = [
    {
      name = "worker-group-1"
      instance_type = "t3a.medium"
      asg_min_size = 1
      asg_max_size  = 3
      asg_desired_capacity = 2
      root_volume_type = "gp3"
      root_volume_size = 20
    }
  ]

  map_users = [{
    userarn   = "***"
    username  = "****"
    groups = ["****"]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make ALB working with following

```
EKS - 1.22
aws-load-balancer-controller - v2.4.1 
istioctl - 1.14.2
```

First I modified istio-ingressgateway service type from load balancer to node port.

```
istioctl install --set profile=default --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.type=NodePort -y
```

Then create ingress. Here is my ingress. I only configured to support port 80

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: istio-alb
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-aaaaaaa, subnet-bbbbbbbb, subnet-cccccc
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxxxxxxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz/ready
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: "32560"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: istio-ingressgateway
                port:
                  number: 80
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

I believe adding security group annotation will solve your issue.